problems [group] by Contact form 7
The logic is this: when choosing a city, we open a specific form with clinics for each year. However, recently we saw in the form that we were unloading forms with all the clinics and the [group] tag did not work. The form opens when you click on the "Записаться" button.
<div class="contact-form-wrp">[hidden formTitle class:formTitle]
<div class="contact-form-row"><label>Выбрать город</label>[select* ep-city class:chosen-select "Москва" "Санкт-Петербург" "Самара" "Сочи"]</div>
[group group-3]
<div class="contact-form-row">
<label>Выбрать клинику[select* ep-office class:chosen-select include_blank "м. Новокузнецкая" "м. Маяковская" "Хамовники" "м. Ломоносовский проспект" "м. Ботанический сад" "Красногорск" "Коммунарка" "Химки" "м. Курская"]</label></div>
[/group]
[group group-4]
<div class="contact-form-row">
<label>Выбрать клинику[select* ep-office2 class:chosen-select include_blank "Полозова, 30" "Загородный просп., 17"]</label></div>
[/group]
[group group-5]
<div class="contact-form-row">
<label>Выбрать клинику[select* ep-office2 class:chosen-select include_blank "Самара"]</label></div>
[/group]
[group group-6]
<div class="contact-form-row">
<label>Выбрать клинику[select* ep-office2 class:chosen-select include_blank "Сочи"]</label></div>
[/group]
<div class="contact-form-row sservice sservice_serv">
<label>Выбрать услугу</label>[select* ep-serv multiple class:chosen-select class:multi-choice include_blank "Эпиляция" "Косметология" "Аппаратный массаж"]</div>
<div class="contact-form-row"><label>Личные данные</label>[text* your-name class:basic-input placeholder "Ваше имя*" ]</div>
<div class="contact-form-row">[tel* your-tel class:basic-input placeholder "Ваш телефон*"]</div>
<div class="contact-form-row">
<label>Предпочтительная дата и время[select* yes-date  class:chosen-select include_blank "Сегодня! Нет времени ждать :)" "Завтра с 10 до 12" "Завтра с 12 до 14" "Завтра с 14 до 16" "Завтра с 16 до 18" "Послезавтра" "Другая"]</label></div> 
<div class="contact-form-row">
[text text-243 class:promocode placeholder "Промокод"]</div> 
[text text-739 class:service_vib class:hidden]
<div class="form-accept">[acceptance acceptance-272 checkbox checkbox-174 default:on ""]<span class="checkbox-text"><noindex><a href="/privacy-policy/" target="_blank"> Я даю согласие</a></noindex> на обработку моих персональных данных*</span></div>[submit class:basic-button class:send "Отправить"]
</div>

link to page:https://epilate-me.ru/
I tried to write logic using JavaScript, but it didn’t work.

where is your script?

[group group-3] shortcode not works properly

check your Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7 plugin. Seems it is inactive. Activate the plugin and check.
